# How to invoke a script on some action on ticket on bmc remedy?

Tags: remedy

The requirement is to invoke a shell script/.bat file on some action done on BMC remedy's incidents. 
After some research, it looks filter is the answer. But, on BMC remedy GUI, can't find any link to create a filter.

Update: 
[BMC Doc link](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars81/Creating+filters)

Where is the link to create filter on BMC GUI ?? Have logged in as admin too.

Answer (score 1):

If the link is right, you are using Remedy 8.1 version. You need the BMC Remedy Developer Studio tool to create a filter.

Then in the filter you have to add an "run process" action with the unix or window command that runs the script.